# navigation navGraphViewModels cause IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

In my code I do like this:
`private val accountDetailsViewModel: AccountDetailsViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.account_subgraph) { defaultViewModelProviderFactory }`

But it crashes on firebase crashlytics:

No destination with ID 2131361857 is on the NavController's back stack. The current destination is a(ph.com.globe.globeonesuperapp:id/dashboardFragment) label=DashboardFragment class=ph.com.globe.globeonesuperapp.dashboard.DashboardFragment

I tracked the code and noticed that the crash is from`findNavController().getBackStackEntry(navGraphId)` . The destination is not on the back stack. But I don't know why and how can I fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when tried to use ViewModel in the fragment's `onCreate` method.

Using `onStart` instead solved this issue.